# Displaying C# compilation warnings in Sonar?

Tags: sonarqube

We use Sonarqube for displaying source health, and we have the FxCop integration working and showing the appropriate messages.

However, I can't seem to find any way to also have Sonar show warnings as a rule violation?  (CS0169, CS0067, CS1591, etc)  I see many of the CAxxxx rules, but nothing for the CSxxxx rules?

Is there something I'm missing?  Is it at all possible to show compilation warnings on our page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for this good feedback. Compiler warnings are not yet supported by the SonarQube C# plugin. The good news is that, with Roslyn, this should now be quite straightforward to implement from a technical point of view. I have commented on the following ticket to make sure we keep track of this feature request: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-113