# SonarQube: include files outside of the project into analysis

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I'm testing SonarQube with a .Net solution file. I'm trying to figure out which files exactly get uploaded/imported into the SonarQube database. Based on my tests with the SonarQube MSBuild runner, it analysis and uploads all files which are stated in the .csproj project file(s) (only those that can be associated with a language plugin because I have set "Import unknown files" to false).

Is there a way to specify additional files which should be analyzed and imported? I had some hope for the "sonar.inclusions" setting, but it's not exactly what I need because the description says *Patterns used to include some source files **and only these ones** in analysis.*

I'd like to just specify **additional** files.

My use-case: at the moment, SonarQube does not create issues for compiler warnings (see [Displaying C# compilation warnings in Sonar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814291/displaying-c-sharp-compilation-warnings-in-sonar)) (which in my opinion is really sad/weird for a tool that wants to improve code quality). So my idea is to use msbuild with an xml-logger, import the generated xml log file and use the XML plugin with custom XML path rules to extract the compiler messages.

Similar issue for analyzing Delphi code. I found an old SonarQube Delphi plugin which I could not yet get to work with SonarQube 5.x, but I'd like to try to get at least the compiler messages into SonarQube (convert Delphi compiler output into XML, get SonarQube to import this file, use custom XML path rules).

Is there a way to get SonarQube to analyze/import such additional files?